# Emacs from scratch

Tags: unix, emacs, text-editor

I planning switch to `Emacs` and my wish is to do it smoothly, extending core of emacs with extensions I need over time, what is why main distribution looks too bloated.

It is not any pleasant when so much of choices is made for me. I have some free time at weekends to install plugins I need and write scripts in elisp to serve my goals.

Games, VCS* utils, some other stuff.. this is so-o excessive
(*I prefer using git via command line + aliases & bash functions).

---

**Questions**:

- Are there other distributions or I should manage installation and cleanup it myself?
- Is removing packages/extensions is all I need or they pre-compiled in some more complex ways?
  If that is so, emacs looks pretty mush like "box" software, which is kinda weird.

So I want lightweight (bare?) Emacs and, after I get comfortable with it and feed my passion to *play* with it, switching to over-complex version is possible.

---

`Emacs 24` is preferred because of lexical scoping added into elisp.

Comment: The installation is bundled with lots of stuff, but almost none of it is "on" by default. Is there something about vanilla GNU Emacs that annoys you? If you're on a Unix platform you could always check out [XEmacs](http://xemacs.org/).

Comment: I agree with the first half of Daniel's comment, but I wouldn't recommend XEmacs to anybody in 2015. That project is about as dead as they get, and GNU Emacs has never been stronger. The vast majority of Emacs packages available today (some of which you may want) are written for GNU Emacs 24+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As @DanielLyons said, just because something is implemented and distributed as part of Emacs does not mean that you will load it. There is plenty that is distributed that I never use - and never load (including the gigantic Gnus).
2. As far as I know, there is no "lightweight" Emacs distribution.
   Just use the normal distribution.  Don't load (`require`) what you don't need, and you will be fine.
3. And there will be plenty of opportunity for you to add your own extensions or extensions developed by others. ;-)
4. You can always delete subdirectories of code that you are sure you will not use, to save disk space, if that is really a problem.

In sum, don't worry about the Emacs "footprint".  It's not that big on disk these days, and your memory footprint depends on what you load.